# Learn thermodynamics before beginning with control engineering ?

Tags: thermodynamics, control-engineering

I'm about to start learning about control engineering. But am I advised to learn first Thermodynamics? (Since control engineering has applications in Thermodynamics)

Comment: control engineering has applications in nuclear power ...

Comment: @SolarMike you mean it's not so related to thermodynamics as it is to nuclear power?

Comment: If you have to ask, you don't get it...

Comment: well I'm still a beginner and it seems to me that it has some connection, I just aim to start right with it

Comment: Most engineering degrees have the basics across most disciplines... then you choose a specialization - well, one way to have a good grounding anyway...

Comment: Okay so I need to get the basics well in control engineering first and then learn about special field it's concerned about

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like an [academic guidance question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/261/1832). Such questions often involve personal choice and can probably be better answered by an adviser or counselor. We do not believe this site's format is well-suited to such questions, which are therefore considered off-topic.

Comment: Control engineering has applications in every engineering discipline. If you want to apply it to control *systems that involve thermodynamics*, then you need to know some thermodynamics, but you don't *need* to know any thermodynamics to understand control engineering.

Comment: @alphazero thermodynamics has some nice and simplifyable systems to model that are easy to implement, and thus used as examples. But yeah thermodynamics also has some hard parts ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to understand the aspect at play on the control side of processes before first understanding how the process behaves.  Thermodynamics, fluid mechanics/dynamics, unit operations, kinetics, etc. will all improve your process knowledge and make what you are learning in controls much easier to implement appropriately.  The first two listed would be very important in the learning phase in order to understand the why behind most control operations.

Comment: Probably the reason is that thermodynamics has many processes that can easily be seen as simple one dimensional lumped systems. Giving you meaningful simulations that are still simple to understand, such as heat exchangers, room temperature control etc. Same can not be said of bar mechanisms for example.